# Unable to filter duplicate elements using set

Tags: python, spacy

I am unable to filter duplicate tokens in dataframe. The tokens are obtained from spacy tokenizer.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy('en')
df['KeywordDoc'] = [nlp(text) for text in df.Keyword]
df['KeywordDoc'].head()
```

output

```
0                                (test, test, test, .)
1                                              (media)
2    (immigration, behavior, and, attitudes, ;, soc...
3    (computer, automation, and, design, ;, human, ...
4    (computer, automation, and, design, ;, human, ...
Name: KeywordDoc, dtype: object
```

Here, i try to filter duplicate from one row

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(set([i for i in x['KeywordDoc']])), axis=1)[0]
```

Output

```
[test, test, test, .]
```

Expected output

```
[test, .]
```

Comment: Does `df["KeywordDoc"].apply(lambda x : list(set(x)))` work  ?

Comment: Pandas apply acts as a row wise function so you mainly get unique elements per row basis instead of unique elements per dataframe

Comment: just do `df['KeywordDoc'] = {nlp(text) for text in df.Keyword}`

Comment: What is your end goal? Keeping your texts in pandas df is a bit unconventional for NLP.

Comment: @NathanFurnal  Thanks for the input but the output still contains the duplicate text

Comment: @Shijith Thanks for the input but the output still contains the duplicate text

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I want to remove the duplicates. Can you suggest any alternative  ?

Comment: @jlandercy I want to remove duplicates on row level. Thanks

Comment: @joel no problem, I can't replicate your issue, it works well on my toy dataframe with a tuple in each cell, are the words individual strings or has the whole tuple been converted to a string somehow?

Comment: `df['KeywordDoc'] = [set(nlp(text)) for text in df.Keyword]`

Answer (score 0):

Try if you want unique keywords per row (note `tok.text`):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

texts = ["this is a text","this is another"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"KeywordDoc":texts})
df['KeywordDoc'].apply(lambda row: {tok.text for tok in nlp(row)})
```

or if you want unique keywords for the total df:

```
texts_ = df.KeywordDoc.tolist()
docs = nlp.pipe(texts_)
unique = {token.text for doc in docs for token in doc}
unique
```

or:

```
docs = nlp.pipe(texts_)
unique = []
for doc in docs:
    for tok in doc:
        if tok not in unique:
            unique.append(tok)
```

or even (less efficient because you call nlp per row)

```
unique = set()
df['KeywordDoc'].apply(lambda row: unique.update([tok.text for tok in nlp(row)]))
print(unique)
```

If you strive for efficiency do not forget switch off unnecessary pipelines like `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable = ['ner', 'tagger', 'parser'])`

Comment: @joel Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers